# Why is a `\n` appended to every value in the python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

My code is:

```
quiz = {}
quiz["questions"]={}
templist = []

def checkint(i):
    try:
        int(i)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


with open("sample",'r') as f:
    for x in f:
        x.rstrip()
        num,text = x.split(" ",1)
        print(text)
        num = num[:-1]
        if checkint(num):
            quiz["questions"][num] = {}
            quiz["questions"][num]["question"] = text
            templist.append(num)
        else:
            qn = templist.pop()
            quiz["questions"][qn][num] = text   
            templist.append(qn)
```

The sample file is:

```
1. Who is the sower in the parable of wheat and tares?

 a. Jesus

 b. Peter

 c. Angels

 d. Satan
```

When I print the dictionary quiz, the output contains newline `\n` at the end of every value.

> {'questions': {'1': {'a': 'Jesus\n',    'b': 'Peter\n',    'c':
>   'Angels\n',    'd': 'Satan\n',    'question': 'Who is the sower in the
>   parable of wheat and tares?\n'},   '2': {'question': '\n'}}}

Why is this so? What should I do to get rid of the `\n`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with dictionaries -- your lines read from the file would still have trailing newlines if you never wrote them to a dictionary at all. Please in the future try to produce a [mcve] with elements not strictly necessary to recreate the problem removed.

Comment: `x = x.strip()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rstrip` return a copy of the string with trailing characters removed.

Change this:

```
x.rstrip()
```

To:

```
x = x.rstrip()
```

**EDIT:**

The second argument you give in `num,text = x.split(" ",1)` means that :

> if maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done (thus, the list
>   will have at most maxsplit+1 elements). If maxsplit is not specified
>   or -1, then there is no limit on the number of splits (all possible
>   splits are made).

If there is nothing to split you will get this error.

Have you tried `num,text = x.split(" ")`?

Or at least one split is a mandatory?

Comment: I get this error: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: @OneFace , on which row do you get this error?

Comment: num,text = x.split(" ",1) - this line gives that error

Comment: @OneFace, added explanation at my answer.

Comment: I think I got why I got that error. The last line has only one element. Thanks for the answer

Comment: You are welcome, Good luck !

Comment: @gabrielbelini: In the provided code `num` will never be an instance of `int`.

Comment: @Matthias My bad then. I got the thing totally wrong, he is trying to convert the str to int, and not check if it already is an integer